# How to build VSFTPD?

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I have just downloaded the VSFTPD-3.0.2 distribution and opened to find lots and lots of intimidating files. I read the INSTALL file and got myself even more confused!!!

So can anyone out there give me simple & easily understandable instructions to build VSFTPD preferably from terminal??

I'm using xubuntu 14.04

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: 14.10 is in development, and isn't supported here. That said, vsftpd 3.0.2 is in the repositories, not sure why you need to build it.

Comment: Oh SORRY I meant Xubuntu 14.04

Comment: Both 14.10 and 14.04 have vsftpd 3.0.2 in their repositories. Why build it, instead of installing?

Comment: This question is followed up from [this one](http://askubuntu.com/q/493066/158442), I think. Instructions are provided in the link I posted, please use them.

Comment: Thanks how do I find out what the server address is?

Comment: And how do I edit the /etc/vsftpd.conf file